# How to update specific row in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, where I store user uploaded files. There can be 5 different file types: profile picture, cpr file, degree file, video file, background check file.

Table structure is this:

```
file_id, user_id, file_type, file_size, file_name, file_new_name, file_path, file_cat, date_created
```

My questions:

1. Is this structure efficient or should I create 5 different tables?
2. If I would like to update, lets say user profile picture row, then what would be the best way to do it? --- I came up with a solution that probably is not be the best one- I update the row where `file_cat = "profile_picture" and user_id=:user_id`. Would that put a lot of load in the system?
3. First when user signs up, he doesn't have any files. Should I user `insert into ... VALUES ... on duplicate key update` with a hidden value in a form?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't store files in a database, store them on disk. Refer to the location of the file in your database.

Comment: Regarding the structure - It's just my opinion but profile pictures are gonna be accessed often so it may be a good idea for them to have their own table. The queries for them should return much faster than if they are stored with the rest.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes. the files are stored on disk, the paths are in DB

Comment: The title in the question and your actual questions differ.

Comment: If you can store all the relevant information for all file types in a single table without having columns that are specific to one or other type, then yes, they should all be in a single table. You would only need to create separate tables if each type had data that was unique to that type. Even then, you would probably want a single main table, with separate tables just to hold those unique data fields; you wouldn't want to replicate your whole main table structure five times.

Comment: If you store the profile picture file, with the user id in the filename, then you don't need a database row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is three questions not one.

> Is this structure efficient or should I create 5 different tables?

One table is good enough

> If I would like to update, lets say user profile picture row, then
>   what would be the best way to do it? --- I came up with a solution
>   that probably is not be the best one- I update the row where file_cat
>   = "profile_picture" and user_id=:user_id. Would that put a lot of load in the system?

Not if you have an index on file_cat, user_id (composite index on both fields). If you want to make things a bit leaner you can store constants instead of 'profile_picture' etc. eg

```
profile_picture = 1
cpr = 2
....
background = 6
```

This would make the tables and indexes a bit smaller. It *might* make the queries slightly faster.

> First when user signs up, he doesn't have any files. Should I user
>   insert into ... VALUES ... on duplicate key update with a hidden value
>   in a form?

No need for that. not having a record for new users actually makes things easier. You can do an `COUNT(*) = 0` query or better still an `EXISTS` query without having to fetch rows and examine them.

Update:
These EXISTS queries are really usefull when you are dealing with JOINs or Sub Queries for example to quickly find if a user has uploaded a profile picc

```
SELECT * from users WHERE exists (SELECT * from pictures where pictures.user_id = users.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example on if exists query?

Comment: I used row count. Seems more work, but it works. Performance wise, are there any differences between row count and if exists?

Comment: yes, exists only needs to check one row. Count needs to count all the matching rows

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

If you use the primary key properly then your `insert ... on duplicate key update ...` query will do everything for you.

For your table you need to define a primary key column.  In this case I would say it is your `file_id` column.  So if you do your insert, the MySQL server will check to see if your `file_id` column is defined already for that value, if so it will update with the new values, other wise it will add a new row of data with the new `file_id`.

I should be easy enough to separate it though, make 1 script for creating new rows and another for updating.  Usually you will know when you are creating as opposed to updating in an application.  Again using a primary key correctly will help you out a lot.  Using a primary key in your `where` clause I am pretty sure is one of the most efficient ways to update.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Appreciate it a lot